# How can I upgrade ember 2.7 to 3.28?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

My team inherited an old (around 2017) ember.js based project, and we need to choose between remake the project with vue, or just upgrade ember version.

The project use node 6.16, and here are the dependencies :

```
// package.json
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.2.0",
    "chart.js": "2.2.1",
    "ember-ajax": "0.7.1",
    "ember-browserify": "1.1.13",
    "ember-cli": "2.4.2",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-autoprefixer": "0.6.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.5",
    "ember-cli-chart": "3.1.0",
    "ember-cli-chartjs": "2.3.1",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.3.5",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.10.2",
    "ember-cli-moment-shim": "2.2.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^1.2.1",
    "ember-cli-release": "0.2.8",
    "ember-cli-sass": "5.3.0",
    "ember-cli-spinjs": "1.0.8",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-cookies": "0.0.9",
    "ember-data": "^2.18.5",
    "ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.4",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^0.5.0",
    "ember-models-table": "1.11.0",
    "ember-moment": "7.0.0-beta.3",
    "ember-pikaday": "2.1.0",
    "ember-power-select": "1.0.0-beta.14",
    "ember-resolver": "^2.0.3",
    "ember-rl-year-picker": "^0.2.0",
    "liquid-fire": "0.24.0",
    "loader.js": "^4.0.0",
    "semantic-ui-ember": "2.0.0-beta.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ember-colpick": "^0.6.2",
    "findup": "^0.1.5",
    "semantic-ui-icon": "^2.3.3"
  }
}
```

```
// bower.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "~2.7",
    "ember-cli-shims": "0.1.0",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "0.2.2",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.1.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.6",
    "matchMedia": "0.2.0",
    "semantic-ui": "^2.2.4",
    "chartjs": "2.1.6",
    "spin.js": "^2.3.2",
    "mjolnic-bootstrap-colorpicker": "^2.3.6",
    "colpick": "2.0.2",
    "pikaday": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "js-cookie": "^2.1.2"
  }
}
```

Yes the project use bower & npm, no idea why.

Knowing this, I got some questions :

- Is this normal that ember-cli from npm has not the same version as ember from bower ?
- Do you think it is even possible to upgrade ember from 2.7 (or 2.4.2??) to 3.28 (which is LTS) ?
  We tried to use the famous `ember update` and `ember-cli-update` but it seems that our version (2.4.2) of ember-cli doesn't support it. We can't even find from which version this is supported.
- If this is possible, then how ?
- Is it possible to get rid of bower ? Before upgrading or after ?

The project is quite large, so we would like to avoid remaking it with vuejs.

And to answer the "why upgrading ember ?", well, node 6 is awful. We need at least node 12

Answer (score 9, accepted):

every version is upgradable! But the safest way to do so is probably to traverse from LTS to LTS.

So, 2.4 -> 2.8 -> 2.12 -> 2.16 -> 2.18 -> 3.4 -> 3.8 -> 3.12 -> 3.16 > 3.20 -> 3.24 -> 3.28

[*More information about Releases here*](https://emberjs.com/releases/)

That may sound like a lot of work, but it's why it's so important to keep up with upgrades. (It may not actually be that much work, depending on the size of your app, and how much you get distracted by new features)

The general strategy at each step is:

- have a good test suite
- loop:

  - ensure you have 0 deprecations being logged while running tests
  - upgrade all libraries to the highest they can go while supporting your version of ember (this'll require some spelunking, but thankfully, you don't have very many non-default deps)
  - upgrade your ember-source version to the next LTS

Getting off bower is a little non-standard though (in that it's a one-time thing), but there are some blog posts to help you out:

The 2x release blog posts: https://blog.emberjs.com/tag/version-2-x
The 3x release blog posts: https://blog.emberjs.com/tag/version-3-x

From reading the 2-x blog posts, I found this migration guide for getting off bower: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v2.13.0-beta.1

- I'd probably try to do this first, because you can do the nice upgrade loop described above

However, since you're thinking about re-writing in Vue, it may make sense to just re-write in Ember 4.2 instead -- since a lot of the concepts transfer (if you're not familiar with the latest ember, I cannot recommend [the tutorial](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/part-1/) enough, as it's hard to top.

For a full list of features there is this app: https://upgrade.emberjs.com/changes?fromVersion=2.4&toVersion=4.2

(It says to run some commands, I wouldn't do either of those commands being as far back as 2.4)

For better support through you're upgrade, I recommend joining ember's discord server: https://discord.gg/emberjs

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, you're a king. 
When you say "Getting off bower is a little non-standard though", do you mean that ember version 2.4 standard is to work with bower ? Or ember standard overall ? Actually, we thought removing bower would simplify the work, since it is unknown to us. And we also not used to have multiple package managers. Do you think we should keep it ?

Comment: I just mean that getting off bower is a special one-time upgrade task that you don't need to worry about again. You're absolutely right that getting away from it would make things easier.

Comment: additionally, the soonest you can add ember-auto-import to your app, the more simple dealing with third-party npm packages will be in general

Comment: I would add to this that you can upgrade ember-cli /ember-cli-babel etc. extremely far even without upgrading many other things. I might start there. Get the build tooling all the way to either latest or 3.28.x and then begin the ember-source migrations.

Comment: Note, upgrading build tools first also means you get to move to latest node sooner too :)

Comment: Based on the release date, ember-cli-update probably will work when you get to Ember 2.12 or 2.14. IIRC, ember-cli-update will remove Bower but can only do that for the ember packages. It looks like most of the Bower packages are being used by the Ember addons in package.json devDependencies. Newer versions of those addons should pull those from npm when they’re upgraded

Comment: another important thing: if you have some dependencies that changed a lot, that are only used in one or two places, it might make sense to just commend these pieces out, and remove the dependency, for the immediate updates. and then when you reached your final version try to manually handle this component/dependency.